# How to check the checkbox state then show/hide the next input field in Django template

Tags: javascript, django

Dears,
My GOAL is to use the `{{ form.is_scholorship }}` this field ,which is type of `models.BooleanField` in the models.py, to determine whether next field `{{ form.scholorship_amount }}` shows.

I am not sure how to take `form.is_scholorship` as tag and pass to javascript function to set next field show/hide or do more actions with this variable.

Here is my code.

In the template:

```
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.is_scholorship.errors }}
                <label class="form-label">獎學金</label>
                 {{ form.is_scholorship }} 
            <button type="button" onclick="test()"> 測試 </button>    
            </div>
           
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.scholorship_amount.errors }}
                <label class="form-label">獎學金金額</label>
                {{ form.scholorship_amount }}   
            </div>
           
        </div>
```

In the models.py:

```
class Case(models.Model):
   .
   .
   .
    is_scholorship=models.BooleanField(verbose_name="獎學金",default=False)
    scholorship_amount=models.IntegerField(verbose_name="獎學金金額",blank=True,default=0,null=True)
```

Hope someone can help me to figure out handling Django variable in javascript.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, where is js code ?

Comment: @Swati Sorry that I removed it. Cause I have no idea how to pass {{form.is_scholorship}} to javascript function and judge whether my {{ form.scholorship_amount}} input tag in html needs to set disabled, like " document.getElementById("id_scholorship_amount").disabled;"

Comment: are you open with jquery ? Also you need to hide/show or disable ?

Comment: @Swati Yes. I also tried to use jQuery to do that. I need to disable in some conditions and some input labels read-only. (Example: Input the student's name then automatically insert the name of student's school into next input label.) Sorry that poor english, wish you can know what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use conditions in Django templates check this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if)

so your template should be something like this:

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.is_scholorship.errors }}
                <label class="form-label">獎學金</label>
                 {{ form.is_scholorship }} 
            <button type="button" onclick="test()"> 測試 </button>    
            </div>
           
        </div>
       {% if form.is_scholarchip %}
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="fieldWrapper">
                {{ form.scholorship_amount.errors }}
                <label class="form-label">獎學金金額</label>
                {{ form.scholorship_amount }}   
            </div>
           
        </div>
       {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `change` on your checkbox. So ,whenever user check or uncheck checkbox this event will get call and then depending on if checkbox is checked or not you can disabled or enabled your next input i.e : `prop("disabled", false)` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //onchange of checkbox ..
  $(".outer input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    //get closest outer div and then -> next outer div->input
    var slector = $(this).closest(".outer").next().find("input")
    //check if the checkbox is checked or not..
    $(this).is(":checked") ? slector.prop("disabled", false) : slector.prop("disabled", true)
    //or to hide/show :
    //$(this).is(":checked") ? slector.closest(".outer").show() : slector.closest(".outer").hide()
  })

  $(".outer input[type=checkbox]").trigger("change")

})
//read more here -> https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--added outer ...class-->
<div class="form-group col-md-6 outer">
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label class="form-label">獎學金</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6 outer">
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <label class="form-label">獎學金金額</label>
    <input type="number">
  </div>

</div>
```